# Are there any good articles on raking in seasonal adjustment?

Tags: time-series, references, seasonality

I am trying to learn about the "raking process" in seasonal adjustments.

I had not heard of it before but I see it mentioned in a couple government stats publications (such as: https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/11-522-x/2021001/article/00020-eng.pdf).

I have tried Googling, of course, but am unable to find any references.

Comment: Your link has a reference to Quenneville, B. and S. Fortier (2011), “Restoring Accounting Constraints in Time Series – Methods and Software for a Statistical Agency”, in W. R. Bell et al. (eds.) Economic Time Series: Modeling and Seasonality, Chapman and Hall/CRC, pp. 231-254.

Comment: It also says *"Raking is done so that component series sum to an aggregate series when they are seasonally adjusted independently"* which suggests that seasonally adjusted components do not always add up to seasonally adjusted totals - perhaps the effect of different multiplicative adjustments not reacting consistently over summation -  and so further adjustments are needed.  (I suspect that a different process gets, for example, seasonally adjusted quarterly data to add up to the actual annual total.)

Comment: Ah thank you, I missed that!